# How to observe the visibility of a child node?

Tags: javafx, visibility, parent

When a parent node becomes invisible a child becomes invisible too without modifying child visible property. So how can the visibility of a child node be observed without observing all parent nodes and the hierarchy? Is there a proper event fired?

Comment: i know the answer im just not sure brb. +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to achieve what you want. There is no property to observe and no event is fired when the parent visibility changes.

You can take a look at the internal implementation of `Node.parentPropertyImpl()`, which basically does what you want to avoid: it adds an `InvalidationListener` to the parent's `impl_treeVisibleProperty` (internal API and deprecated).