# Is it possible to create dynamic Bindings.OR in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Lets consider the following situation. There is a `Pane parentPane` and there are `Pane firstChildPane, secondChildPane, thirdChildPane ...`. Child panes are added to parent pane. How can I make parentPane be visible only in that case if any of child pane is visible taking into consideration that child panes can be added and removed dynamically without any limit and in any order. Of course childPane visible state can be also changed any time. Is it possible to create dynamic Bindings.OR in order I could add/remove child visible property to/from it dynamically? If yes, then how? If not, then what solutions are used in such cases?

Comment: Give a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185073/how-to-observe-the-visibility-of-a-child-node

Comment: Related: [Multiple Boolean Binding in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192963/multiple-boolean-binding-in-javafx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something along the following lines:

```
// list that fires updates if any members change visibility:
ObservableList<Node> children = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(n -> new Observable[] {n.visibleProperty()});
// make the new list always contain the same elements as the pane's child list:
Bindings.bindContent(children, parentPane.getChildren());
// filter for visible nodes:
ObservableList<Node> visibleChildren = children.filter(Node::isVisible);
// and now see if it's empty:
BooleanBinding someVisibleChildren = Bindings.isNotEmpty(visibleChildren);
// finally:
parentPane.visibleProperty().bind(someVisibleChildren);
```

Another approach is to create your own `BooleanBinding` directly:

```
Pane parentPane = ... ;

BooleanBinding someVisibleChildren = new BooleanBinding() {


    {
        parentPane.getChildren().forEach(n -> bind(n.visibleProperty()));

        parentPane.getChildren().addListener((Change<? extends Node> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
               c.getAddedSubList().forEach(n -> bind(n.visibleProperty()));
               c.getRemoved().forEach(n -> unbind(n.visibleProperty())) ;
            }
        });

        bind(parentPane.getChildren());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean computeValue() {
        return parentPane.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(Node::isVisible)
            .findAny()
            .isPresent();
    }
}

parentPane.visibleProperty().bind(someVisibleChildren);
```

Comment: Now it is my turn to comment that [the factory method you are using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindContent-java.util.List-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) states "Once a List is bound to an ObservableList, the List must not be changed directly anymore. Doing so would lead to unexpected results.", so `bindContentBidirectional` seems like a safer choice...

Comment: @sillyfly But `children` won't be changed directly here (it's easy enough to make it a local variable, or otherwise encapsulate it, so it can't be changed directly)

Comment: Huh... I have not realized it was the other way around! It seems a bit counter-intuitive that it is the non-observable list that gets "bound" to the observable one (and so the observable one is the one that can be safely changed), but I guess that's the only way that makes sense.

Comment: @sillyfly I always have to pause for a moment with that method, but, yes, you can only bind *to* something that is observable, which determines which way around it is. (But either way, you want `children` to be dependent on `parentPane.getChildren()`...)