# JavaFx: merge boolean properties

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, boolean-operations

I have a `List<BooleanProperty>`, how can I merge them with `or`?

I need something like:

```
private BooleanProperty getMergedProperty(List<BooleanProperty> properties){
     return mergeAllWithOr(properties);
}
```

Or:

```
private BooleanBinding getMergedBinding(List<BooleanProperty> properties){
     return mergeAllWithOr(properties);
}
```

`mergeAllWithOr` means `list.get(0).or(list.get(1)).or(...`

**Edit:**
This is what I have tried, but it works as an `and` not an or:

```
private BooleanProperty getMergedProperty(List<BooleanProperty> properties) {
    BooleanProperty property = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    properties.forEach(property::bind); // or donesn't work at all.
    return property;
}
```

Can you please suggest any solution?

Comment: You can use the same method described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200663/is-it-possible-to-create-dynamic-bindings-or-in-javafx/46201034#46201034

Comment: Ohh thank you, finally I managed to do using the answer by creating a new `SimpleBooleanProperty`, then loop through the list and bind the elements to the created proeprty, sorry if this is a duplicate of that, but I didn't find it.

Comment: @sillyfly the problem is `.bind` is working like an `and` so the problem is still present, i cannot get the solution to wirite a simple `or` binding among them. Did i understand wrong that answer or what did I miss?

Comment: @Sunflame Why don't you try it the same way as in the linked question? The "solution" you have won't work at all: property binding means the property has the same value as the property to which it is bound. If you call `bind` on a property it will remove any previous binding. So your code just results in the property being bound to (having the same value as) the last property in the list.

Comment: Okay, now I think I understood how it is working, initially i thought a little bit different that's why wasn't working for me. Now I did similar that you wrote down, and works. I'm still thinking about if I can use `Bindings.createBooleanBinding()` instead of `new BooleanBinding()`.